# Apex without sharing not working in Public Visualforce page

Tags: apex, force.com, sharing

I have a unauthenticated website which I'm trying to expose data on, however I am having issues getting the data displayed. I suspect this is because of the changes [Winter 2020 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_networks_guest_sharing_security_update.htm), but assumed we could bypass this using `without sharing`.

When I print out the data using the following nothing is returned:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!shows}" var="item" id="theRepeat">
    <div>
        <apex:outputText value="Id: {!item.Id}"/><br/>
        <apex:outputText value="Name: {!item.Name}"/><br/>
        <apex:outputText value="Centre: {!item.Account.Name}"/><br/>
    </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public without sharing class ShowsController {
    public Shows__c loadShows() {
        showList = [SELECT id, name, Account.Name FROM Shows__c WHERE Id =: idNeedle]; 
    }
}
```

In my Guest Site Profile, Shows__c has Read All Access however I can't do the same for Account.
Will declaring `without sharing` still bypass the security settings or has Salesforce super-ceded this?

**Edit:**
Adding some debug lines into the getShows method like this:

```
system.debug('showList[0].Account__r.Name:' + showList[0].Account__r.Name);
```

... does print out the name, so it just doesn't appear in the visualforce page ;/

Comment: Please edit your post to include more details on your specific issues.  Also, check the trailblazer discussion group [Securing Community Cloud](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A0000004mDI) where the Site guest user changes are a major focus.

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: Are the text fields empty or are you not getting any records?

Comment: The records are being returned, Id, Name values are populated, but the Centre values are not. They are empty.

Comment: Remember that Sharing and FLS are different things. If your problem is with "Centre Name", then ensure you have *read* access to the `Name` field on the `Account` object, and to the object itself

Comment: @FlorianHeer The last field is returning null, all the other columns are showing data.

Comment: @SebastianKessel Sorry should have mentioned this, but "Read" access has already enabled Account.Name field on the Guest User Profile via FLS.

Comment: Have you checked the FLS for Account__c? If the user does not have acces to that, Visualforce will not output anything behind the relation either.

Comment: @FlorianHeer The profile only has `Read` (but not `Read All`) access to Shows__c, but declaring `without sharing` it still can retrieve other records. With `Account` (sorry its not `Account__r`), as its a standard object I cannot set `Read` or `Read All` and the without sharing doesn't affect it.